# crystal reports : splitting delimited field to columns

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I split a delimited field into columns in Crystal Reports XI?

The data in the fields looks like this:

> value1 \t value2 \t value3 \r\n
>
> value1 \t value2 \t value3 \r\n

I would like to format it as

> Value1    Value2   Value3

I tried putting the fields into Crystal but the tab delimiters are not formatting correctly.

It displays as:

> Value1   Value2Value3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need three formulas:

```
//{@one}
Split({table.field}, " \t")[1];

//{@two}
Split({table.field}, " \t")[2];

//{@three}
Split(Split({table.field}, " \t")[3], " ")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Cyrstal Reports 2013 edition as well. I have a column which was separated by ',' and creating multiple formulas worked. Thank you @craig :)

```
Split({table.field}, ",")[1];
```